# how to create charts and end user front end navigation from php and mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, database, charts, frontend

I have  a php host, and a mysql database. from that i wish to create charts and diagrams using  the mysql db in php. so for example pie charts, bar charts and so on. I'm open to options on this.

further more I would like to be able to create a front end in php that will allow the end user to be able to navigate records from the database and then be able to generate said charts based on the database.

I am familiar with MS Access and some mysql and a tiny bit of php (I have already created the tables and populated with records and such).

so it would be similar to how in MS Access you can create an application/front end and allows the user to peruse records, without being able to create new records, but also generating reports and charts based on the data.

Is this doable with mysql and php, could someone guide me in the right direction and I'll take on board any suggestions you may have to accomplish this.

It will be going into a website, so the user can interact with the site and do as above.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is super broad question. The answer is: Yes, this can be done with PHP/MySql.
You will require somekind  of API or server side (PHP) chart generation tool if you want to generate images.

I suggest the following charting tools:

- http://code.google.com/apis/chart/
- http://pchart.sourceforge.net/

Good luck.

Comment: thank you both for your suggestions. I tried to be specific and apologise if it was still too vague - however you have both offered excellent solutions. thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [FusionCharts XT](http://fusioncharts.com/). They work very well with PHP, and since the charts are pure JavaScript, you are free to use any database on the backend.

Read the [FusionCharts documentation](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?guide-for-web-developers/php/PHP_BasicExample.html) for more info.